# How do I properly use NUGET, for MVC (ASP.NET) projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I've learned that NUGET will "Always" download the latest package and how to use the -version switch.  However, on a recent project where different developers had different SUO files (Visual Studio) they would have the need to add other NUGET content to satisfy Build errors.  (Yes we shouldn't be doing that ).

But in attempting to clean up the mess, it seems as if NUGET does not clean up everything as it should.  I validated this by debugging an issue and finding that the Web.Config still had bad references just last week.  The problem of course is that the whole dependency chain on these packages is unknown!  This creates circular dependency chains that are most likely the reason why when Uninstalling packages, there is left-over Dlls.

Here's a case in point, last week we were so hosed up, I decided to re-install MVC 4...  Couldn't figure out how to do that simple task other than to compare my last known working version and individually download version specific dlls.  And good luck in finding the more obscure packages which MSFT includes in their own MVC templates.

Just wondering, what do you do, to make this fool proof and what advise can you give me to become an "expert" at controlling my reference libraries?

Comment: (pure rant) You named some of the reasons I really don't like nugets.. but OTOH, there's really no other package management system in this env :( (I mean: I have not found other yet)

Comment: Yah, I'm not a fan because, those darned dependency chains.  I'm working on and older code base too, so if we get hosed with new stuff we have to work like crazy to get the old stuff back.  NUGET does this thing where it will, update an DLL, and then it will mark older code as a dependency of it.  In addition it adds the dreaded Machine Redirects....  Not a good long term solution when trying to figure out the reclusive bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend setting 'Enable Nuget Package Restore' on your solution.  Also ensure that nothing from the packages folder gets into source control. Let the package restore resolve the packages on each machine.  Once you have some packages in Source control you are introducing headaches in managing them (versions, missing references etc.)